# Listing directories not following specific format

Tags: bash, shell, directory, wildcard, ls

I have an assignment where, only using bash one-liners, I must ls the specific directories in my home directory that do not follow a specific naming schema.  In my home directory, there are some directories that have the format of 3 alphabetical lower case letters followed by 3 decimal digits. However, there are other directories that don't follow this format.  I must list those files and output the info to a txt file.  Here are some commands I have written so far and am experimenting with:

```
ls /home -1 | sed [^a-z][^a-z][^a-z].[^0-9][^0-9][^0-9]

ls /home -1 "[^[a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]]"

ls /home -1 *{[^a-z][^a-z][^a-z].[^0-9][^0-9][^0-9]}*
```

Also before anyone asks, I know formatting and searching through the output of the ls command is not as effective as the find command.  But the assignment that I am working on dictates that I may only use these commands: ls, ps, sed, cut, paste, sort, tr, grep, awk, cat, uniq

Comment: If you are allowed to use `sed` then try with `grep -v the_valid_pattern`

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Why do you use so many `^`? Just `[a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]`. Why a `.` in between?

Comment: @KamilCuk `^` is an attempt to match files that *don't* follow the naming schema.

Comment: I found the answer that works: /bin/ls /home -1 | grep -v "^[a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]$"

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `shopt -s extglob` first, then

```
ls -1d /home/!([a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9])
```

If not,

```
ls -1d /home/* | grep -v '/home/[a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]$'
```

PLEASE read the manual pages for `ls`, `grep`, and `shopt`.

If you don't understand why these work, you haven't learned anything, and we're just doing your work for you...

Comment: And make sure you know the difference between file globbing and basic (and extended) regexes.

Comment: Thank you for your concern.  I've managed to figure it out a couple of hours ago.  The issue was with my aliases in my directory.  I managed to fix it by appending the unalias command to the beg of my script.  The command I used is /bin/ls /home -1 | grep -v "[a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]"